# spark-excel dataype issues

Tags: excel, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-poi, spark-excel

I am using [spark-excel](https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel) package for processing ms excel files using spark 2.2. Some of the files are getting failed to load as a spark dataframe with below exception. If someone have faced this issue can you please help to fix such data type issues?

After analyzing I found at that if column name is not a string, it ends up giving below exception, If I manually change the column name to string from integer, it works fine.

**Code:**

```
  val excelDF = spark.read.
    format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").
    option("useHeader", "true").
    option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true").
    option("inferSchema", "true").
    option("addColorColumns", "False").
    option("sheetName", sheetName).
    load(filePath)
```

**Exception:**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a STRING value from a NUMERIC cell
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.typeMismatch(XSSFCell.java:1077)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.getRichStringCellValue(XSSFCell.java:395)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.getStringCellValue(XSSFCell.java:347)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation$$anonfun$inferSchema$1$$anonfun$10.apply(ExcelRelation.scala:206)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation$$anonfun$inferSchema$1$$anonfun$10.apply(ExcelRelation.scala:205)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation$$anonfun$inferSchema$1.apply(ExcelRelation.scala:205)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation$$anonfun$inferSchema$1.apply(ExcelRelation.scala:204)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation.inferSchema(ExcelRelation.scala:204)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation.<init>(ExcelRelation.scala:91)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:37)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:14)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:8)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:156)
```

Answer (score 1):

The new version of `com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.11:0.12.5` library works with non string column/header names as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a more elegant answer for this I would post this as comment, but do not have the required reputation.

I always try to ensure that my column headers are strings.

Also as a rule I do not have numeric characters in the column headers and we have a simple script that replaces the numeric with alphabetical characters (i.e. 1 by one).